# How to set objects on a frame properly wit wxpython toolkit?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Please advice the most appropriate parenting way to achieve the following layout with wxpython toolkit. The image below shows how I did it, for some reason GRID1 and GRID2 are not responsive to mouse clicks, whereas there are no problems with GRID3. When I click on any cell on GRID1 or GRID2, the cell is not highlighted, and when I double click on any cell on GRID1 or GRID2, editor doesn't start.

[image]

Comment: Please create a small runnable example that demonstrates the issue. Knowing what version of Python/wxPython and OS would be good too. It sounds a lot like a parenting issue though.

Comment: You were right, it was because of a parenting issue, now it is fixed. Would you use a splitter window or a sizer to split grid 1 and grid 2?

Comment: Or would you use a grid sizer to place grid1, grid2, grid3 and chart panel all at once?

Comment: I would probably use a sizer. Splitter windows are for scrolling lots of widgets. Grids already have scrollbars builtin. You could use a grid sizer to hold them if you want. That's up to you.